# launch.json breaks debugging in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I wanted to set `justMyCode` to false for a python project in VSCode.
So I created a `launch.json` file in a `.vscode` folder under the project root folder with the following content:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal", // <== adding/deleting this makes no difference
            "env": {"PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT": "5"}, // <== I'd like to have this too
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ],
    "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true,
    "jupyter.debugJustMyCode": false,
}
```

Afterwards, the debugger won't start. The code runs fine outside the debugging tough.

What should I modify?

Comment: After using your launch configuration, whether using **Debug Python File** button or **F5**, I can run normally. Have you tried to restart vscode?

Comment: the top-right triangle-run-button does NOT use launch configs

Comment: BTW, it seems that you missed `"version": "0.2.0",` at the top of `launch.json`

Comment: Do you get any related messages in the output logs (`View > Output`)?

Comment: @rioV8 That's true, but after I deleting "version": "0.2.0", in `launch.json`, I can't debug through the top-right triangle-run-button while F5 can.

Comment: Yes, I tried to restart. 
"version" does not seem to make any difference.
I do not get any messages in Output.
and..
THANKS!! F5 works! stupid triangle button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rioV8 said, debugging through the **Debug Python File** button in the upper right corner will **not** read the configuration in `launch.json`.

You can use shortcuts **F5** or click the following button in the picture:

[image]

Some relevant supplementary information:

| Run option | .env setting | launch.json setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Run Python file in terminal | no | no |
| Run in interactive Window | yes | no |
| Debug via F5 | yes | yes |
| "Debug Python File" (*) | yes | no |